# Unable to start service com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService

Tags: android, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

When receiving data message from server, this error log is display:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.sample.test, PID: 30964
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService@d69f855 with
> Intent { act=com.huawei.push.action.MESSAGING_EVENT
> pkg=com.sample.test (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4683)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:296)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2259)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
> at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.logger.HMSLogger.setupEventMap(HMSLogger.java:292)
> at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.logger.HMSLogger.(HMSLogger.java:78)
> at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.logger.HMSLogger.getInstance(HMSLogger.java:95)
> at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService.onMessageReceived(HmsPushMessageService.java:35)
> at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:185)
> at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.onStartCommand(HmsMessageService.java:131)
> at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService.onStartCommand(HmsPushMessageService.java:90)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4663)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:296) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2259) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)

Comment: It's a Push Kit bug, and we are working on it. It will be fixed in the next version updated by the end of October.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a known bug and it has been rectified already. Please update React Native Push Plugin to the latest version **5.0.2.301** [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library/reactnative-plugin-0000001050155850?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 1):

Version `5.0.2.301` solved my issue working with `react-native@^0.63.4`. But it doesn't work with the latest version of the plugin available today (`5.1.1-301`).

@shirley FYI

Comment: hi Walter Devia,thank you for your feedback,could you please provide your complete log, so that we can analyse your problem. You can get the complete log from the following steps.

The procedure for capturing logs is as follows:

1. Run the following command to connect to the device:

    adb logcat –v time > D:\hwpush.log

2. Reproduce the fault.

3. Press Ctrl+C to complete log capture.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are using data messages, if yes tell me how you get data from notification?
EX:
In this code we are receiving "id" data message which we post from console or server:

```
   override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage?) {
    Log.i("OnMesageReceived", "onMessageReceived is called");

    //data notification -get data
    val id = message!!.dataOfMap["id"]
```

}

Comment: I am able to get the data by using "message.getData()":
    

@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        Log.w(TAG, "** onMessageReceivedData **" + message.getData());
        Log.w(TAG, "** onMessageReceived **");
        HMSLogger.getInstance(this).sendPeriodicEvent("onMessageReceived");
        HmsMessagePublisher.sendMessageReceivedEvent(message);
    }